# linq using IN Operator in split comma values

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am getting the following results for

```
string[] proj = Pid.Split(',');
```

"1032,1222" --> [0]=1032,[1]=1222

but I want to use in LINQ query. This is my LINQ query.  Where to use it and how to use it?

```
string[] proj = Pid.Split(',');

var data2 = (from p in Db.emp.AsEnumerable()
             join r in Db.use on p.EmployeeId equals r.EmployeeId
             join q in Db.proo on p.EmployeeId equals q.EmpId
             where (q.IsDelete == false && p.IsDelete == false && p.RoleID != 1 && p.RoleID != 2 && q.ProId == Convert.ToInt32(Pid))
             select new GroupSelectedModel { 
                 Text = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName), 
                 Value = r.UserId.ToString(),
                 StatusId = Convert.ToInt32(p.Status)
             })
            .Distinct().ToList().OrderBy(r => r.Text);
return data2.OrderBy(p => p.StatusId).ToList();
```

Please check above mentioned code.

Answer (score 0):

When you need `IN`, you have to invert it, and use `Contains()`. Your post is not very clear, but I think you're asking for something like this (note you need to use a `List` instead of an array):

`List<string> proj = new List<string>(Pid.Split(','));`

`where (q.IsDelete == false && p.IsDelete == false && p.RoleID != 1 && p.RoleID != 2 && proj.Contains(q.ProId))`